# Editing AJAX sourced data in the popup window (jquery-datatables-editable)

Tags: datatables, jquery-datatables-editor, datatables-1.10

DataTables Editable plug-in has a sample for [editing data in the pop-up window](https://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn-history/r287/trunk/ajax-popupedit.html). But I can't seem to be able to get this working when data is sourced from ajax (using `sAjaxSource` property). In the demo the `Edit` link is hard-coded in the HTML, but when data is dynamically loaded we cannot hard-code anything. Can anybody please explain how to do this or give me a pointer for help?

Thanks!